# JessTab in Protege

Tags: jess

I'm using `Jess` with `Protege`, I created a `def template Person`  with the `slots (name, age and adress),` and I created another `def template` which `extends` the first one with the additional slot (sex), now I want to delete the first one and replace it by the new one, and I don't want to lose instances, I want the instances of the first one to be extended by the second, how can I do it ?
thank you

i tried first to modify the structure of the def template with the function `"replace$`", but it doesn't work, then I tried the function "`modify`" but it just modifies the value of a slot

```
(deftemplate Person (slot name(type string)) (slot age(type integer)) (slot adress(type string)))

(deftemplate Personne (slot name(type string)) (slot age(type integer)) (slot adress(type string)) (slot sexe (type string) ))

(assert( Person (name "Bryan") (age "25") (adress "New York")))

(assert( Person (name "Omar") (age "35") (adress "Algeria")))

(assert( Person (name "Sara") (age "30") (adress "Moroco")))
```

When I tried to use the function `"replace$`" into a rule, I had no syntaxique error, the syntax is correct, but when I do (run) it does not work, no rule is executed.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to change the instances themselves during a single run of the program. But you could save them to a file, edit the file, and load them back in.

Comment: hy, thank you, would you clarify please, i want the second deftemplate to extend the instances of the first one with the aditionnal slot (sex) and delete the first one and be replaced by the second one , and keep its relations (object propertiés) ,  thank you